# Замена многострочного текста в файле с кавычками

Tags: linux, bash

Необходимо в файле найти по шаблону (регулярка) текст и заменить его на
другой многострочный текст в котором присутствуют разные кавычки: `'`, `"`.  Попробовал заменить через *Perl*, он ругается что там встречаются кавычки...

Исходный текст:

```
foo bar
text
baz quux
```

Текст, который хочется получить:

```
foo bar
line1
"line2"
'line3'
baz quux
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код,пример что из текста есть и что хотите в итоге получить

Comment: Возможно кавычки надо экранировать, смотря как вы запускаете скрипт и как передаете аргументы

Comment: @PotroNik Perl -i -p0e пытаюсь в файле заменить строку *тут нужен текст* заменить на многострочный текст с одинарными и двойными кавычками, я пытался их экранировать одним \ . Но команда падает сообщая что встретилась неожиданная кавычка..В самом многострочном тексте, кавычки не создают конфликтов, все имеют пару и не пересекаются

Comment: В тексте вопроса (ссылка "править" под текстом вопроса) явно напишите всю команду целиком, которую выполняете. Невозможно ничего сказать о том, правильно ли вы экранируете строку, не видя эту самую строку

Comment: @ИванКакуркин  Немного подредактировал ваш вопрос, добавив примеры кода из своего ответа, чтобы можно было проголосовать за переоткрытие.  Я предполагаю, что раз вы приняли мой ответ, ваши примеры достаточно похожи на мои.  Если вы не согласны, пожалуйста, замените примеры на свои.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не привели примеров текста или вашего кода, так что я угадываю.
Вот вариант с *GNU sed*:

```sh
$ sed -e 's/text/line 1\n"line2"\n'"'line3'"'/' -i -- ./txt.tmp.txt
```

Более переносимый (но и более уродливый) вариант с *POSIX ed*
и *POSIX printf*:

```sh
printf '%%s/text/line1\\\n"line2"\\\n'"'line3'"'/\nwq\n' | ed -s -- ./txt.tmp.txt
```

Вариант с *POSIX ed* и *POSIX more* на несколько строк:

```sh
more <<-'EOF' | ed -s -- ./txt.tmp.txt
    %s/text/line1\
    "line2"\
    'line3'/
    wq
EOF
```

Все варианты заменяют `text` на:

```
line1
"line2"
'line3'
```